# How to use asio buffer after async_read_until for consecutive reads

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I am reading from a serial device where each message must be specifically requested. E.g. you send a request and get a response with the serialised payload.

Each message contains these parts in order:

1. PREAMBLE (2 bytes, "$M")
2. HEADER (3 bytes, containing payload length N)
3. PAYLOAD+CRC (N+1 bytes)

My approach with asio is to detect the start (PREAMBLE) of a message by using `asio::async_read_until` and afterwards using `asio::async_read` for reading the exact amount of bytes for HEADER and PAYLOAD+CRC. Since there is no static pattern at the end of the message, I cannot use `async_read_until` to read the full message.

After receiving PREAMBLE, the handler for `async_read_until` gets called and the buffer contains the PREAMBLE bytes and might contain additional bytes from HEADER and PAYLOAD+CRC.
The asio documentation for async_read_until says:

> After a successful async_read_until operation, the streambuf may
>   contain additional data beyond the delimiter. An application will
>   typically leave that data in the streambuf for a subsequent
>   async_read_until operation to examine.

I interpret this as that you should only consume the requested bytes and leave all remaining bytes in the buffer for further reads. **However, all consecutive reads block since the data is already in the buffer and there is nothing left on the device.**

The reading is implemented as a small state machine `processState`, where different handlers are registered depending on which part of the message is to be read. All reading is done with the same `buffer` (`asio::streambuf`). `processState` is called in an infinite loop.

```
void processState() {
    // register handler for incomming messages
    std::cout << "state: " << parser_state << std::endl;
    switch (parser_state) {
    case READ_PREAMBLE:
        asio::async_read_until(port, buffer, "$M",
            std::bind(&Client::onPreamble, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
        break;
    case READ_HEADER:
        asio::async_read(port, buffer, asio::transfer_exactly(3),
            std::bind(&Client::onHeader, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
        break;
    case READ_PAYLOAD_CRC:
        asio::async_read(port, buffer, asio::transfer_exactly(request_received->length+1),
            std::bind(&Client::onDataCRC, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
        break;
    case PROCESS_PAYLOAD:
        onProcessMessage();
        break;
    case END:
        parser_state = READ_PREAMBLE;
        break;
    }
    // wait for incoming data
    io.run();
    io.reset();
}
```

The PREAMBLE handler `onPreamble` is called when receiving the PREAMBLE:

```
void onPreamble(const asio::error_code& error, const std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    std::cout << "onPreamble START" << std::endl;
    if(error) { return; }

    std::cout << "buffer: " << buffer.in_avail() << "/" << buffer.size() << std::endl;

    // ignore and remove header bytes
    buffer.consume(bytes_transferred);

    std::cout << "buffer: " << buffer.in_avail() << "/" << buffer.size() << std::endl;

    buffer.commit(buffer.size());

    std::cout << "onPreamble END" << std::endl;
    parser_state = READ_HEADER;
}
```

After this handler, no other handlers get called since the data is in the buffer and no data is left on the device.

**What is the correct way to use `asio::streambuf` such that the handlers of consecutive `async_read` get called and I can process bytes in order of the state machine?** I don't want to process the remaining bytes in `onPreamble` since it is not guaranteed that these will contain the full message.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the call to `buffer.commit()` in the `onPreamble()` handler. Calling `buffer.consume()` will remove the header bytes as you expect and leave the remaining bytes (if any were received) in the `asio::streambuf` for the next read. The streambuf's `prepare()` and `commit()` calls are used when you are filling it with data to send to the remote party.

I just finished a [blog post and codecast](https://v1ntage.io/2017/08/21/an-asio-http-client-in-15-minutes/) about using the asio::streambuf to perform a simple HTTP GET with a few web servers. It might give you a better idea of how to use `async_read_until()` and `async_read()`.